# Using a mult-argument Predicate with Filter in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to use filter with a predicate with multiple arguments? If so, how would I do it under the context of this code:

```
   ;predicate
    (defn classInstructor [instructor class]
      (str/includes? class instructor))
    (defn instructorClasses [instructor classList]
      (filter classInstructor classList))
```

Comment: `(filter #(classInstructor instructor %) classList)`

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function can take a function that applies to several arguments. For example,

```
=> (map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
(5 7 9)
```

The `+` gets two arguments, one from each sequence. There is no corresponding version of `filter`. You could extend the standard `filter` as follows:

```
(defn filter
  ([f coll]
   (clojure.core/filter f coll))
  ([f coll & colls]
   (filter #(apply f %) (apply map vector (cons coll colls)))))
```

For example,

```
=> (filter (comp odd? +) [1 2 3] [4 6 8])
([1 4] [3 8])
```

As you can see, we have to present the surviving sequences somehow. I don't find it persuasive or natural to do so. Not worth doing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so, using an anonymous function:

```
(defn classInstructor [instructor class]
  (str/includes? class instructor))

(defn instructorClasses [instructor classList]
  (filter #(classInstructor instructor %) classList))
```

This way, when one calls `instructorClasses`, the value of `instructor` is passed through to `classInstructor`.

Comment: Or `(filter (partial classInstructor instructor) classList)`.